# Background script chrome.tabs is undefined in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried this:

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (activeTab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
      });
    });
});
```

foo.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    new contentFunction()

    console.log(sender.tab ?
      "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
      "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello") {
      sendResponse({ farewell: "goodbye" });
    }
  });
```

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "foo",
  "browser_action": {

  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"

  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["foo.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to call the contentscript js fro the extension button press

Comment: It runs in a different context so you need to use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

Comment: @wOxxOm thx,I don't see the content script downloaded in the network tab to test. The extension click calls the background function which is good

Comment: Your code is almost correct: use chrome.`tabs`.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {greeting: 'hello'}, .....

Comment: chrome.tabs is undefined @wOxxOm

Comment: Eh? chrome.tabs is defined in the background script.

Comment: not when I run it im afraid, pls see my edit

Comment: The code is correct and chrome.tabs must be defined in the background script. Make sure you've reloaded your extension, checked the console for background page (not the web page), and reloaded the tab so that the content script is reinjected.

Comment: I dont see the contentscript in the network tab, I've reloaded the extension too. I don't have a  background page, just a  background script.

Comment: 1. Content script isn't loaded like a network resource so you won't see it there 2. Background script is a shorthand that generates a background page, which has its own context and console: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029) 3. Make sure to read the [extension architecture article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)

Comment: please see my chrome object screenshot

Comment: It's either a bug in the browser which I never witnessed myself during the years of developing chrome extensions or somehow you didn't actually add "tabs" or "activeTab" permission in manifest, or didn't reload the extension.

Comment: thx 4 your help so far. Manifest is as seen in OP. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: thx, all the code is in the OP

Comment: It works here: https://puu.sh/wCUQx/9833a44edd.png

Comment: roger, ill try disable my other extensions

Comment: So after I disabled all the extensions and enabled mines, chrome tabs is defined. However this returns a 0 length array: **chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}**

Comment: The issues you encounter do not make any sense to me, I have never encountered anything like that so I can't help you anymore.

Comment: no worries, I will open a big bounty in a few hours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681477/background-script-messaging-with-javascript/29683574#29683574

Comment: Well, obviously a devtools window doesn't have any tabs so chrome.tabs.query doesn't return any!

Comment: i mean if any of the chrome settings windows are in a tab it causes the issue

Comment: `chrome settings windows are in a tab` - what does it mean?

Comment: I had to refresh the pages when the extension is reloaded, i didnt realise this

Comment: thx for your help

Comment: I started to have the same problem again (